# What is the meaning and usage of the word "very" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> XSLT (Extensible Stylesheet Language: Transformations) is a language that, according to the ***very*** first sentence in the specification (found at http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/), is primarily designed for transforming one XML document into another.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here, the word "very" is used to put additional emphasis on the word it modifies: "first". It's a shorthand for saying

> XSLT is a language that, according to the specification — *in fact, not just any place in the specification, but the first sentence of it* —, is primarily designed for transforming one XML document into another.

Or:

> XSLT is a language that is primarily designed for transforming one XML document into another — that's what the specification at http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/ says *right* in its first sentence.

Comment: nicely explained ...

Answer (score 3):

In this case, "very" is used to give emphasis to "the first sentence."

Answer (score 1):

It is used in the sense of "true". "Very" is derived from a Latin word which means true. It is the root of veritas.

Comment: Yes, but this meaning is archaic and little used in the modern language.

Comment: @ColinFine: It nevertheless explains this usage very well.